# Can't get transition effect happening when closing a side sliding menu

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I am having an issue getting a transition effect happening when closing the side menu and not sure how to get it working properly. It looks like it should work but it doesn't want to

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

});

$('#Toggler').on('click', function() {
  $('#SideBarNavSlide').toggleClass("SideBarNavSlide2");
});
```

```css
#SideBarNavSlide {
  width: 225px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  height: 100%;
}

.SideBarNavSlide2 {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div id="TheContainer" class="container-fluid" style="border:1px solid red; background-color:pink;padding:0; margin-top:0px;">
  <div id="headerMenu" style="width:100%!important;height:35px;background-color:cyan;">
    <button id="Toggler" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:4px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
  </div>
  <div id="SideBarNavSlide">
  </div>
  <div id="ContentArea" style="float:right; border:1px solid white; background-color:purple; width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; margin-left:225px!important;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="border:1px solid black; background-color:yellow; position:fixed;height:100%; width:100%; margin-left:20px!important">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `#SideBarNavSlide{transition: width 2s;}`?

Comment: @Stickers, I did have that added earlier in the css, but it did nothing for me

Comment: Maybe the class selector didn't apply since ID has higher ranking  you may try `#SideBarNavSlide.SideBarNavSlide2`, but it's better to remove the ID and use a class.

Comment: But again, the previous comment still applys, as you need to add the transition to the original state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

id is more specific and gets higher priority than classes .. so you simply need to use `#SideBarNavSlide.SideBarNavSlide2{` instead of `.SideBarNavSlide2{`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Toggler').on('click', function() {
    $('#SideBarNavSlide').toggleClass("SideBarNavSlide2");
  });
});
```

```css
#SideBarNavSlide{
  width: 225px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  height: 100%;
}

#SideBarNavSlide.SideBarNavSlide2{
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: width 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div id="TheContainer" class="container-fluid" style="border:1px solid red; background-color:pink;padding:0; margin-top:0px;">
  <div id="headerMenu" style="width:100%!important;height:35px;background-color:cyan;">
    <button id="Toggler" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:4px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
  </div>
  <div id="SideBarNavSlide" class="anotherClass">
  </div>
  <div id="ContentArea" style="float:right; border:1px solid white; background-color:purple; width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; margin-left:225px!important;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="border:1px solid black; background-color:yellow; position:fixed;height:100%; width:100%; margin-left:20px!important">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes have lesser priority than IDs, so you should use `#SideBarNavSlide.SideBarNavSlide2` instead of `.SideBarNavSlide2`. Moreover, apply the transition to the initial state to make it work in both directions.

```js
$('#Toggler').on('click', function() {
  $('#SideBarNavSlide').toggleClass("SideBarNavSlide2");
});
```

```css
#SideBarNavSlide {
  width: 225px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  transition: width 2s;
}

#SideBarNavSlide.SideBarNavSlide2 {
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div id="TheContainer" class="container-fluid" style="border:1px solid red; background-color:pink;padding:0; margin-top:0px;">
  <div id="headerMenu" style="width:100%!important;height:35px;background-color:cyan;">
    <button id="Toggler" style="margin-left:10px; margin-top:4px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
  </div>
  <div id="SideBarNavSlide">
  </div>
  <div id="ContentArea" style="float:right; border:1px solid white; background-color:purple; width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; margin-left:225px!important;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="border:1px solid black; background-color:yellow; position:fixed;height:100%; width:100%; margin-left:20px!important">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way, consider using less inline styles.

Comment: And what is the deference between this answer and my answer? or even with @Stickers comment??

Comment: There are four differences: 1. I mentioned how to make it work in both directions. 2. I recommended to use less inline styles. 3. I was just too slow. 4. I have no right to comment, yet, otherwise I even would not have written an answer. That's it.

Comment: ok bro... I hope you got 50 rep soon to be able to comment .. Have a great day :-)